# How to retrieve Facebook's user data from "developer Facebook"

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create a web app for educational purposes in which I required a **search bar** which helps me get Facebook's user data

For example: **username**, **image**

These two fields are enough for me.

Is it possible for me to retrieve such data using React.JS?

Comment: You can only get user data, if the user logs in to your app and grants it permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the basic steps:**

- Create a facebook app and add facebook login to it.
- Setup facebook login allowed SDK URls (where you will call the login method) and redirect URL after login.
- Add needed permissions to your app
- Add facebook SDK scripts to your react index.html or install the SDK.
- Using the SDK call FB.login() and from the response save the user access token
- send a request to FB_API_URL/me to get the user data you want

before all that test your requests to the created app with FB graph API Explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Last step: submit your app for review as most permissions will not work before this step.

**useful links:**
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/get-started
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

[image]